# What is the graphical user interface used to access PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

Is PostgreSQL accessible via phpMyAdmin (like MySQL) or any other similar graphical user interface that could manage it?
Note: the the database is being developed locally using MAMP.

Comment: http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, default GUI for pgSQL is http://www.pgadmin.org/